# AdventureWorks 2014

Tags: windows-7, permissions, sql-server

I'm trying to restore the AdventureWorks2014.bak file.  SQL Server is installed locally and the .bak is saved locally.  I am using the instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhuDtvbpses.  When I run the SQL, I get the following message:

```
"Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLCAST2014\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2014.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally."
```

I checked the permissions on the .bak file.  All of the permissions are set to true except special permissions.  The following page suggested some things for a remedy but I still can't get the backup restored due to my access being denied.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/13/sql-server-fix-error-msg-3201-level-16-cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-5access-is-denied/

Can you recommend any tests that would help me troubleshoot the problem?

Below is the SQL:

```
    USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2014
FROM DISK= 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLCAST2014\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2014.bak'

WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2014_data'

TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLCAST2014\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2014.mdf',

MOVE 'AdventureWorks_log'
```

Comment: "All of the permissions are set to true except special permissions". Permissions for whom? Your user, or the user the SQL services run as?

Comment: I set the permissions for all users.  I am the only person using the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works with these two things:

1. To set the permission of AdventureWorks2014.bak to be accessed to Everyone.
2. Opening Properties window for AdventureWorks2014.bak, to click Unblock button on General tab.

Good luck :)